# Qt: QSplitter, redo sizes

Tags: c++, qt, qsplitter

When the application is launched but yet in construction time (when all the initial widget is being created and so on), I add to my layout a `QSplitter`, with two widgets, and I want the second widget occupies more or less the 60/70% of the available space, while the first widget takes the rest of the space (taking into account the splitter size itself).

So, in the beginning, before the windows itself is shown, I try to readjust these two widget more or less like that:

```
splitter->setOrientation(Qt::Vertical);
auto sizes = splitter->sizes();

int& first_w = sizes.front(); // == 0
int& second_w = sizes.last(); // == 0
int diff = form_w * 2.3 - tbl_w; (30% * 2.3 = ~70%)

second_w += diff;
first_w -= diff;

splitter->setSizes(sizes);
```

But, `first_w` and `second_w` contains `0` and `0`, I don't know if because the sizes have not been calculated yet, or because the widget is not yet shown (the window isn't) and the sizes of invisibles widgets are `0`.

What can I do to get the "future" sizes of these widgets? The `splitter` is inside a `QVBoxLayout`, and the available space of the owner widget is more or less all the vertical space of the window (there's only a `QTabBar` above the widget owning that `QVBoxLayout`, and a bit of padding in the window).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setSizes) the following should do the right thing...

```
splitter->setSizes(QList<int>() << 30 << 70);
```

If the `QSplitter` is vertical that should apportion 30% to the top widget and 70% to the lower.

Comment: No, it doesn't work (I have test that). That values set the sizes in pixels I think, and since there's a lot of free space to be distributed among them, that values are completely replaced by the `sizeHint`s. The offending widget is a `QTextEdit` that there's inside the form which takes too much vertical space.

Answer (score 0):

The method `QSplitter::sizes()` seems to give non-zero sizes only when the widget is shown. What I usually do to circumvent this problem is override `QWidget::showEvent(QShowEvent *event)` and invoke the method `QSplitter::setSizes()` there.

Comment: That's right!! I didn't think about it. But I think it would be a better aproach to connect a slot to the `shown` signal, but, oh!! There's no `shown`  signal!